# Ignore points far away from mean gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot a straight line through a set of data points using gnuplot. The problem is that there are points far away from the mean fitted line that I would like to ignore because they are influencing in a bad way the slope of the line. How can you do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to do the fitting once, and then redo the fitting with a second function and discriminate some data points depending on the value with respect to the first fit. To discriminate the outliers, I assign them a very high variance (in the third `using` column). Using undefined data values with `1/0` in the second column didn't work.

Consider the file `test.dat`

```
1 1
2 2
3 5
4 4
```

For the fitting use:

```
f(x) = a*x + b
g(x) = c*x + d
fname = 'test.dat'
limit = 1

fit f(x) fname via a,b
fit g(x) fname using 1:2:(abs(f($1)-$2) < limit ? 1 : 1000) via c,d

set key left
set offset 0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5
plot f(x), g(x), fname
```

The result with 4.6.3 is:

[image]

#### Explanation of the using statement

With the `using` keyword you can select which columns of the data file are used. The simplest case is `using 1:2`, which uses the first column as `x` and the second as `y` (this is implicitely assumed in the first `fit` call). With e.g. `using 1:2:3` one can use a third column as a weight of the respective data point (in the case of the `fit` command). Here, a high value means a large variance and, therefore, low fidelity (see documentation of the `fit` command).

Instead of only selecting columns, one can also do computations like `using 1:($2*2)`, which multiplies the second column by `2` and takes the result as `y`-value. `$2` is a shorthand for `column(2)`, the parenthesis around the whole statement are required.

So, the `using 1:2:(abs(f($1)-$2) < limit ? 1 : 1000)` does the following: `f($1)` is the value of the previous fit for a certain `x` value, `$2` is the corresponding `y`-value from the data file. So, if the distance `abs(f($1) - $2)` of the data `y`-value from the previous fit result is below a `limit`, then `1` is used as weight. Otherwise a very large weight of `1000` is used, which results in almost ignoring this data point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm new to gnuplot and I don't understand what all those symbols mean. Can you explain what the symbols after fit g(x) fname are doing ?

Comment: @PrenumeNume See my edited answer. BTW, there was a mistake in the `using` statement.