# Gnuplot - How to ignore outliers for the fit?

Tags: gnuplot, outliers

I had started working with Gnuplot and tried out a few things. Now, I was wondering how to automatically remove outliers from the fit. An example is shown in the figure with a data point at 4,50 from the second data set.[image: Outlier in "data set 2" distorts the fit]
And the data set:

I've found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295837/ignore-points-far-away-from-mean-gnuplot), but I couldn't make it work for my example. There might be a lot of different approaches and I'm not that experienced with Gnuplot or similar software. So, I would be glad about suggestions, what would be a possible approach to describe outliers.

I'm using the gnuplottex package in LaTeX (texlive) on Windows 10.
The gnuplot code:

```
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=tikz, terminaloptions={color size 7cm,5cm}]
reset session

$Data <<EOD
#data
x   y1  y2  y3  y4
1   1   6   4   2   
2   4   10  1   1   
3   9   15  0   0.5 
4   16  50  1   2   
5   25  31  4   5   
6   36  42  9   12  
7   49  55  30  23
EOD

datafile = 'data.dat'
set print 'parameters.dat'

#_____________Set the label for data points________________________
set key top left                            # set position of legend
set key Left                                # set raggedleft
set key samplen 2 spacing 1.2 font ",8" # set fontsize and spacing
set key noautotitle 

###1__________Define function and number of columns_________________________
f(x,a,b,c) = a*(x-b)**2 + c
colMin = 2
colMax = 5
set fit quiet nolog
array A[colMax]
array B[colMax]
array C[colMax]

do for [col=colMin:colMax] {
    a=1; b=1; c=4            # some initial values, sometimes 0 or NaN is not a good start
    fit f(x,a,b,c) datafile u 1:col via a,b,c
    A[col] = a;  B[col] = b;  C[col] = c
    
    print sprintf ('%d %.4f %.4f %.4f',col-1,A[col],B[col],C[col])
}

plot for [col=colMin:colMax] datafile u 1:col ls col, \
     for [col=colMin:colMax] f(x,A[col],B[col],C[col]) ls col, \
     for [col=colMin:colMax] keyentry w lp ls col \ 
     title sprintf("$y%d$",col-1)
\end{gnuplot}
```

Comment: "what would be a possible approach to describe outliers" is up to you.  You shouldn't let strangers do statistical analysis for you

Comment: As stated above, I'm not experienced with setting up a code to tell the program to exclude points that are 'obviously' outliers. But that's why I asked for suggestions :)

Comment: "Obviously" isn't actually obvious and depends on choices you need to make for yourself.  What you're calling an "outlier" on that blue line may in fact *not* be an outlier.

Comment: I think what an outlier might be should be up to me

Comment: @KonstantinWeigmann For a minimal (non)working example, please always provide the input data as well.

Comment: Oh, yes. I'm sorry, completely forgot that. I'll be editing the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you have to somehow define what you consider as outlier. There are certainly several ways how to do that. I'm not claiming that this is the best way, just consider it as a starting point.

Some Comments:

- you do a fit with all datapoints
- define an absolute distance `OutlierDist` what you consider as outlier
- plot the data into a table `$NOOUTLIERS` and if the absolute distance to the fitted curve is `>=OutlierDist` then write `NaN` into the second column and the original value into the 3rd column.
- now, fit a second time (without the outliers)
- plot the data, the fitted curves (2nd fit) and if desired the outliers

This can certainly be optimized.

**Data:** `"SO77774328.dat`

```
x   y1  y2  y3  y4
1    1    6   4    2
2    4   10   1    1
3    9   15   0    0.5
4   16   50   1    2
5   25   31   4    5
6   36   42   9   12
7   49   55  30   23
```

**Script:**

```
### remove outliers for fitting
reset session

FILE     = "SO77774328.dat"
PARAMS_1 = "SO77774328_1.par"
PARAMS_2 = "SO77774328_2.par"

f(x,a,b,c) = a*(x-b)**2 + c
colMin = 2
colMax = 5
set fit quiet nolog
array A[colMax]
array B[colMax]
array C[colMax]

set print PARAMS_1
do for [col=colMin:colMax] {
    a=1; b=1; c=4            # some initial values, sometimes 0 or NaN is not a good start
    fit f(x,a,b,c) FILE u 1:col via a,b,c
    A[col] = a;  B[col] = b;  C[col] = c
    print sprintf ('%d %.4f %.4f %.4f',col-1,A[col],B[col],C[col])
}
unset print

# write data to table with outliers --> NaN
OutlierDist = 10   # outlier distance
dev(colX,colY) = abs(column(colY)-f(column(colX),A[colY],B[colY],C[colY])-1) >= OutlierDist ? NaN :  column(colY)
set table $NOOUTLIERS
    do for [colY=colMin:colMax] {
        plot FILE u 1:(v0=dev(1,colY)):(v0!=v0?column(colY):NaN) lc var
    }
unset table

# fit again
set print PARAMS_2
do for [col=colMin:colMax] {
    i = col-colMin   # datablock index
    a=1; b=1; c=4            # some initial values, sometimes 0 or NaN is not a good start
    fit f(x,a,b,c) $NOOUTLIERS index i u 1:2 via a,b,c
    A[col] = a;  B[col] = b;  C[col] = c
    print sprintf ('%d %.4f %.4f %.4f',col-1,A[col],B[col],C[col])
}
unset print

set key noautotitle left top

plot for [col=colMin:colMax] FILE u 1:col ls col-1, \
     for [col=colMin:colMax] f(x,A[col],B[col],C[col]) ls col-1, \
     for [col=colMin:colMax] keyentry w lp ls col-1 title sprintf("y%d",col-1), \
     $NOOUTLIERS u 1:(valid(2) ? NaN : column(3)) w p pt 6 ps 2 lc "red" ti "Outlier"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: That looks awesome! I guess, I'll need some time to understand the code, but thanks a lot :)

Comment: @KonstantinWeigmann glad to hear that it seems to be useful for you. If you need more explanations let me know. Well, I'm not yet completely happy about defining the outlier via absolute distance value. I would prefer some single value which might work similarly for all curves. Using something like percent of deviation from fit function value might not work well for values around zero.

Comment: maybe it's the same problem as with the percent of deviation, but might something like the z-score ((Data Point - Mean) / Standard Deviation) work?
Then you could assign a threshold to the z-score as an absolute value.

Comment: @KonstantinWeigmann Not sure if the distance to the mean of the data values will work. Another thought is to calculate the MSE (mean square error) of the fit. If the outlier is included, the MSE of the fit will be large, and MSE will get smaller if the outlier is excluded. However, you don't know in advance which of your N datapoints is the outlier and you would have to fit N times and each time exclude another point of the N points in order to find the minimal MSE. Well, this doesn't look very practical. I'm sure statisticians have smarter methods.

Comment: gnuplot automatically initialises previously undefined parameter variables to "1". Zero is always a bad start, not least because gp scales the parameters to be of the same order of magnitude before the fit. And complains loudly if you supply zero anyway. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You simply define ordinate values that are too far from the function plot as "NaN", using the ternary operator (a?b:c) :

```
maxdev=1.3 # for example
fit f(x) dataf using 1:(abs(f($1)-$2)>maxdev ? NaN : $2) via <parameters>
```

Absolute vertical distance is of course just the simplest example. A sensible outlier criterion for a given problem will eventually require a lot more thinking to avoid compromising the validity esp. of your fit errors.

Of course you need to have a rather good set of parameters already, or after two or three iterations, *all* points will be far from the current function. So definitely start with

```
 fit f(x) dataf using 1:2 via <parameters>
```

and perhaps then continue with a large value for "maxdev", and reduce it stepwise. Disclaimer: always give a good explanation *why* you exclude datapoints, and mark them as excluded outliers. ;)

```
 plot dataf us 1:(abs(f($1)-$2)>maxdev ? NaN : $2) title "data,\
      dataf us 1:(abs(f($1)-$2)>maxdev ? $2 : NaN) title "outliers", \
      f(x) title "fit"
```

Comment: this is of course in essence the same thing as theozh' answer.